# Scifi novel - One-armed fugitive goes to lower level to get 'combat wetware' installed

Tags: story-identification

Cover art was red, with a dark-skinned guy in gray sweats running from a spider-like ship. I also believe he only has one working arm with the other being some kind of prosthetic(?).

I recall some plot elements

- The guy goes down into lower levels of society (the "station" or moon base or town?). That portion is literately divided by levels
- While hiding out in the lower levels he gets 'combat wetware' installed in his mind and then tries to take back his life.

Comment: Some more info might help. Do you recall the hero's name? Why was he being chased? How did he lose his arm? Was the phrase "combat wetware" specifically used? Who installed the combat wetware? Why was the station divided into levels? Who was on the top level? Was their a female love-interest? Was this a YA novel or something for adults?

Comment: @Valorum  -  we should have a flag `needs more detail` for story ID questions, with immediate link to [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9371) answer of yours.

Comment: Was the precise phrase “combat wetware” used? Also, could it be a Warhammer 40,000 book? That phrase is often associated with the Warhammer 40k universe.

Answer (score 1):

John Meaney's *[Paradox](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/818449.Paradox)* features a one armed protagonist, Tom Corcorigan.

> When Tom Corcorigan, a resident of one of the lower (and poorer)
>   underground strata of the planet Nulapeiron, is given a strange
>   data-crystal by a mysterious woman with obsidian eyes, his purposeless
>   existence is forever changed. The woman turns out to be a Pilot, one
>   of the legendary navigators of the mu-space pathways between worlds,
>   and her few words to Tom are as understated as they are prophetic:
>   "Life is a mortal pilgrimage, my friend." When his mother is abducted
>   shortly thereafter by an all-powerful Oracle (whose ability to
>   truecast the future has kept the status quo for centuries) and his
>   father is killed, Tom sets out on an improbable quest to somehow
>   murder a man who knows the future.

[image]